# Split string using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, string, expression

I need to do a little bit of refreshing with my Java regular expressions.

I basically want to detect an invalid string input and if it is valid I will do something with it.

The data can be of either the form

```
New York,Los Angeles
```

or just

```
New York
```

The names of the cities vary of course, so I can have other forms such as

```
Orlando,West Palm

Miami,Stuart

Stuart

Pompano, Satellite Beach
```

So Basically I want to detect these two types of string formats

- String of any length of only upper and lower case letters and spaces followed by a comma and then another string of any length of only upper and lower case letters and spaces with no space between it and the comma.
- Single string of any length of only upper and lower case letters

There can be no numbers or punctuation marks in either string except for that single comma in the first string. So additional commas are also forbidden.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    try
{
    file = new Scanner(new File(f));
    int i = 1;
    while(file.hasNext())
    {
        String[] cities;
        String data = file.nextLine();

        if(data.matches("[a-z A-Z]+,[a-z A-Z]+$"))
        {
            cities = data.split(",");
            flightLog.addPath(cities[0], cities[1]);
        }
        else if(data.matches("[a-z A-Z]$"))
        {
            flightLog.addCity(data);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Line" + i + " is invalid\n");
        ++i;
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("File does not exist");
}
```

}

Comment: and what did you try already?

Comment: The Java tag is enough for saying "this question belongs to Java language"

Comment: Never mind, I solved it. Forgot to add a "+" to the regex in the else if statement.

Comment: FYI, the condition in your `while` loop should be `file.hasNextLine()`, not `file.hasNext()`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [String.split()?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
"New York,Los Angeles".split(",")
```

Comment: I will be using that, but first I have to make sure the string is in proper form. For example, there can be no numbers or punctuation marks in the string except for that single comma. So additional commas are also forbidden. I am dealing with data taken from a file, so it cannot be hardcoded.

Comment: @user1642677 that's not stated in your question. Show some effort first and ask where in your code you have problems. SO won't do the dirty work for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll post what I've done so far.

Comment: For "Pompano, Satellite Beach".split(,) the second String will have an  whitespace, thats right. You can remove the whitespace after splitting or you can try this: `"Pompano, Satellite Beach".split(, *)`. For checking if the names are valid you can iterate the Strings after splitting. Try to match this regex `\[^a-zA-z -]\` to detect if there are characters except of a-z, A-Z, " " or "-".

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it, but you need a regex "[look arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html)" to assert that while the strings may *contain* spaces, spaces may not be adjacent to the comma.

Try this for your first condition:

```
data.matches("^[a-z A-Z]+(?<! ),(?! )[a-z A-Z]+$")
```